# How to navigate to position in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, json

I would like to navigate to position in text file.

Not line number, but character position. Absolute character position from the beginning of file.

How to do this in Notepad++?

Any other plain text editor is ok. I am editing JSON file.

Comment: Could you give an example please? Do you want to go to Nth character of Nth line?

Comment: @Toto no, I want just Nth character in the file.

Comment: @Biswa yes, about cursor; the same thing which is moving when navigating to line number

Comment: I personally use home key, end key and Ctrl+Shift+arrow keys to navigate in b/w words.

Comment: From the menu, Search -> Go To... (or Ctrl+G). Then click the "Offset" radio button, type in your character offset position and hit Go. Doesn't work great for hitting the middle of CR/LF but otherwise seems good.

Answer (score 22):

There's an 'Offset' option you can use to directly go to the character you want.

Select the `Search -> Go to...` menu option (or press Ctrl+G) and change the radio button from **Line** to **Offset** then enter the character position you want to go to in the **You want to go to** field:

[image: Goto offset]

Answer (score 3):

Not very elegant, but it works:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=^.{55}).`
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*

This will highlight the 56th character from the begining of the file.

Comment: FYI: I tried this approach to try and find column 128072 and notepad chugged pretty hard... still works but ugh.